# How to change Orchard CMS default image folder path

Tags: xml-rpc, orchardcms-1.7, windows-live-writer, metaweblog

I have Orchard CMS setup and working correctly. When using windows live writer to create pages it maps images to a folder like /Media/Default/WindowsLiveWriter folder

Eg. 
/Media/Default/WindowsLiveWriter/testpost-title_12A72/sample_image_2.jpg

I don't want my urls to have technology specific sections like "WindowsLiveWriter"

1) How can I customize this in Orchard 1.7 code. I want to have an image url structure like

/Media/Default/2014/March/02/sample_image_2.jpg or
/Media/Default/MyBlog/testpost-title_12A72/sample_image_2.jpg

2) Is there an option in live writer to specify the folder on which the images should be dropped? E.g. use date as a sub folder?

3) Can I change the meta data live writer receive to tell it where my image folder is?

I searched the entire Orchard 1.7 code base for a string WindowsLiveWriter (which is part of the url) but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the file 
\src\Orchard.Web\Modules\Orchard.MediaLibrary\Services\XmlRpcHandler.cs

as follows. 
There is a method called

```
private XRpcStruct MetaWeblogNewMediaObject(
                string userName,
                string password,
                XRpcStruct file,
                UrlHelper url){

        }
```

Inside that change the name of the file at the beginning before response  being sent to MS word blog template for live writer.

```
    var name = file.Optional<string>("name");
    name = Path.GetFileName(name);
    name = "images/"+DateTime.Now.Year+"/"+DateTime.Now.Month+"/" + name;
```

The complete method now looks like

```
   public void Process(XmlRpcContext context) {
        var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(context.ControllerContext.RequestContext, _routeCollection);

    if (context.Request.MethodName == "metaWeblog.newMediaObject") {
        var result = MetaWeblogNewMediaObject(
            Convert.ToString(context.Request.Params[1].Value),
            Convert.ToString(context.Request.Params[2].Value),
            (XRpcStruct)context.Request.Params[3].Value,
            urlHelper);
        context.Response = new XRpcMethodResponse().Add(result);
    }
}

private XRpcStruct MetaWeblogNewMediaObject(
    string userName,
    string password,
    XRpcStruct file,
    UrlHelper url) {

    var user = _membershipService.ValidateUser(userName, password);
    if (!_authorizationService.TryCheckAccess(Permissions.ManageMediaContent, user, null)) {
        throw new OrchardCoreException(T("Access denied"));
    }

    var name = file.Optional<string>("name");

    name = Path.GetFileName(name);
    name = "images/"+DateTime.Now.Year+"/"+DateTime.Now.Month+"/" + name;

    var bits = file.Optional<byte[]>("bits");

    string directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(name);
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(directoryName)) { // Some clients only pass in a name path that does not contain a directory component.
        directoryName = "media";
    }

    try {
        // delete the file if it already exists, e.g. an updated image in a blog post
        // it's safe to delete the file as each content item gets a specific folder
        _mediaLibraryService.DeleteFile(directoryName, Path.GetFileName(name));
    }
    catch {
        // current way to delete a file if it exists
    }

    string publicUrl = _mediaLibraryService.UploadMediaFile(directoryName, Path.GetFileName(name), bits);
    _mediaLibraryService.ImportMedia(directoryName, Path.GetFileName(name));
    return new XRpcStruct() // Some clients require all optional attributes to be declared Wordpress responds in this way as well.
        .Set("file", publicUrl)
        .Set("url", url.MakeAbsolute(publicUrl))
        .Set("type", file.Optional<string>("type"));
}
```